# How to sum values in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

Can someone help me in sum values in VueJs
im try to get a sum of products
All my products display in select options tag by v-for
Im add event on click and after this im get price value in method
If someone have info about solved this problem im so gratefull

this is my code in Vue component

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="typo__label col-sm-3 col-form-label">Продукты</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <multiselect selectLabel="Выбрать" deselectLabel="Удалить" selectedLabel="Выбрано" @input="setSelected"
      :taggable="true" v-model="formData.products" :options="this.$store.state.order.products" :multiple="true"
      :hideSelected="true" :custom-label="titleWithPrice" :close-on-select="false" :clear-on-select="false"
      :preserve-search="true" placeholder="Выберите продукты" label="title" track-by="id" :preselect-first="true">
      <template slot="selection" slot-scope="{ values, search, isOpen }"><span class="multiselect__single"
          v-if="values.length &amp;&amp; !isOpen">{{ values.length }} options selected</span></template>
    </multiselect>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is my code in method

```
setSelected(value) {
            let prices = value;
            prices.forEach((price) => {
                this.price = price.price
            })
        }
```

this is my code in computed

```
 totalItem: function(){
            let sum = 0;
            this.items.forEach(function(item) {
                sum += (parseFloat(item.price));
            });

            return sum;
        }
```

Comment: Is the `setSelected` method working fine?

Comment: use computed properties for this kind of calculation in vue

Answer (score 0):

If the `formData.products` is correctly setting the values selected, then you can directly get the sum of values from the computed section.

```
computed:{
  sum : function(){
    let products = this.formData.products;
    return products.reduce((a,b)=>{
      return parseFloat(a.price) + parseFloat(b.price);
    })
  }
}
```